# Invisible tekst in firefox form

Tags: php, firefox, invisible

I develop site, and I got this bit of code, my problem is it works fine in chrome, but in every other browser when I input txt in input field its invisible (can't see what I type)

Any ideas?

```
<h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;">INVISIBLE TEXT IS HERE :</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <input type="text" name="deposit_wallet" style="padding: 10px 10px; width: 500px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: #006374;" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="deposit_username" value="<?=time();?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="deposit_start" class="button theme-btn" value="Continue" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Just tried on FF 53 and I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: I supposed that your page background colour is white and the colour of text is defined to be white color: #fff;

Answer (score 0):

So just change the text color property like this: color: #000;

```
<h2 style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #000;">INVISIBLE TEXT IS HERE :</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <input type="text" name="deposit_wallet" style="padding: 10px 10px; width: 500px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: #006374;" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="deposit_username" value="<?=time();?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="deposit_start" class="button theme-btn" value="Continue" />
    </form>
```